# jwPlayer not working properly in IE 9 but works on chrome and ie 10

Tags: internet-explorer-9, jwplayer, internet-explorer-10

my self hosted jwplayer doesn’t work with ie9 but it works with chrome and ie 10. Any help that you guys can offer would be greatly appreciated.  The code is listed below.

```
    <html>
    <head> 
    <title>HTML 5 RTMP Test</title> 
    <script src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script>jwplayer.key="keycode=="</script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <div id="player">
    <a>Loading the player...</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         jwplayer("player").setup({
         width: "461",
         height: "282",
         primary: "flash",
         autostart: "true",
         sources: [{
                   file: "rtmp://mydomain.com/livewebcast/v1/livestream",
               },{
                   file: "http://mydomain.com/v1/livestream/playlist.m3u8"
             }]
           });
    </script>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you have Flash for IE9 installed? I see no reasons as to why this would break.

Comment: Yes i do have flash for ie9 installed here is a link to the page:  http://jaxdev.net/jwvod.html

Comment: I see the issue, will answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a test on my local using this code and it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HTML 5 RTMP Test</title> 
<script src="http://www.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script>jwplayer.key="l48FHv8PjETbc5w2agtD9xbH/+6TpnnXHRWRKg=="</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player">
<a>Loading the player...</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
    width: "650",
    height: "360",
    primary: "flash",
    autostart: "true",
    sources: [{
            file: "rtmp://mywebsite.com:1935/vod/sample.mp4",
        },{
            file: "http://mywebsite.com:1935/tphimvod/mp4:sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8"
        }]
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Words cannot express how thank full I am, thank you so much for your fast response. Where was the error?

Comment: I just changed the doctype, that was it. The code was totally fine :)

Comment: Just donated to your website. I have one further request. I have a WordPress site with jwplayer installed, how do i accomplish the same thing using WordPress.

Comment: Thank you! If you are using WP, you just need to make sure that the theme you are using has this doctype - <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: I want to say thank you again for donating. You are the first person who has done so :) So I want to deeply thank you again for that, that really means a lot to me. :-) !